# Cannot access DOM element with captureSelector in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to scrape some images (in this instance Ads) with CasperJS by taking screenshots of just the ads. I've identified a unique ID for the DIV "creative_xxxxx" however I've been unable to access the selector, or any of the selectors in the below image, thus far.

The selectors are not on the page source, presumably because they're inserted during page load, but can be seen in FireBug:

[image]

Essentially I wanted to know how to access the above selector, or more generally any selector which is not in the original page source. I thought Casper executed JavaScript making this a non-issue but perhaps I've misunderstood?

The selector is inside an iFrame and I've used `casper.withFrame(frame, function()` but the selector still doesn't seem to be there. This is the site I'm trying to scrape from:

http://www.trustedreviews.com/vacuum-cleaners

Answer (score 1):

Ads are sometimes (usually?) loaded dynamically. Oftentimes the ad element identifiers are dynamic, so you need to try a partial identifier match. This is possible with CSS selectors:

- `#id_123` exact match for `id="id_123"`
- `[id ^= "id_"]` match from the beginning or
- `[id *= "id_"]` match somewhere in the attribute `id`

Example code:

```
casper.withFrame(..., function(){
    this.captureSelector("ad.png", "[id^='DfaVisibilityIdentifier'] > [id^='creative']");
});
```

Note that PhantomJS doesn't support flash. So, flash-based ads will be either white or black.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it is possible that this doesn't work correctly for elements inside of frames.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize Flash wasn't supported - I take it this would make scraping the ads impossible with Casper then since they're flash banners.

Comment: You can look into SlimerJS in conjunction with xvfb. There is also an [old PhantomJS fork which should support flash](http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/).

Comment: I'll look into the PhantomJS fork. The example code works perfectly but, as you say, results in a white box.